# javascript array key name restrictions

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I'm writing a function to dynamically create a table of calculated values from filtered data within another table on the page.  I want to pass this function an array of table headers (column titles), an array of the table data and an array of the table parameters to set using

```
var tableAttributes = {border:"1px", width:"100%",height:"50px"};
for (attributeID in tableAttributes) {
    table.setAttribute(attributeID,tableAttributes[attributeID]);
}
```

It all works fine until I try to create a key/value pair with a "-" sign

```
var tableAttributes = {border:"1px", border-collapse:"collapse"};
```

when it throws an error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

Is it just a case of popping the keys in double quotes?

Comment: var tableAttributes = {border:"1px", "border-collapse":"collapse"};

Comment: 1) That's an object, not an array. 2) Put the key in quotes: `'border-collapse'`. So, the answer to your question is "yes" :) PS. double or single quotes are fine - just be consistent in their application.

Comment: The problem here is that your question is exactly the solution, why didn't you just try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be a more idiomatic way to achieve what it is you are attempting...

```
var tableAttributes = {
  "border": "1px",
  "width": "100%",
  "height": "50px",
  "border-collapse": "collapse"
};

Object.keys(tableAttributes).forEach(function(element) {
  table.setAttribute(element, tableAttributes[element]);
});
```

If you run this, you should see that properties with dashes work.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the identifiers in quotes if the contain any characters that are in the ill-defined Unicode "Pattern_Syntax". It is *not* a solution, it just kills the symptoms!

The ECMA-script grammar for identifier names is

```
IdentifierName ::
    IdentifierStart
    IdentifierName IdentifierPart

IdentifierStart ::
    UnicodeIDStart
    $
    _
    \ UnicodeEscapeSequence

IdentifierPart ::
    UnicodeIDContinue
    $
    _
    \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
    <ZWNJ>
    <ZWJ>
```

(The `<ZWNJ>` and `<ZWJ>` are zero witdh white space characters)

The grammar explains further

> UnicodeIDStart :: any Unicode code point with the Unicode property “ID_Start” or “Other_ID_Start”
>
> UnicodeIDContinue :: any Unicode code point with the Unicode property “ID_Continue”, “Other_ID_Continue”, or “Other_ID_Start”

The definitions for those are in some tables from the unicode consortium with an example [here](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/4.0-Update/UCD-4.0.0.html). It is a tedious task to squeeze them all out but it has been done by others and you can take a look at it [one of those here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/unicode-6.1.0/blob/master/properties/Pattern_Syntax/symbols.js). A long list, but only the printables ASCII characters are of larger significance in most cases, so don't use the following characters for identifiers if you want to be on the safe side and are using ASCII only.

```
['!','"','#','$','%','&','\'','(',')','*','+',',','-',
'.','/',':',';','<','=','>','?','@','[','\\',']','^','`',
'{','|','}','~']
```

As you can see `$` is in it, too, but we have JQuery? That's why `$` is explicitely listed as allowed in the ECMA-script grammar.